# Not able to use Grouped by unique values as index in Pivot_table Panda DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to filter unique values for product descriptions ( short: description), with a  unique price (net_price).   example:

```
description       net_price       site  
Product 1            9            USCA
Product 2            7            USCA
product 3            6            USCA
product 1           12            USNY
product 2            7            USNY
product 4           10            USBP
```

What I get after filtering  with  `un= master.dropna().groupby('description')['net_price'].unique()`, which is what I  want "A  list of  services   unique  depending on price"

```
description       net_price 
product 1       [9,12]
product 2       [7]
product 3       [6]
product 4       [10]
```

using this: `serv= master.pivot_table(values='quantity', index=un, columns='site', aggfunc=np.sum)` I'm trying to build a pivot table using the unique descriptions  as the index

what I'm  expecting to get

```
                        USCA    USNY    USBP
description 
product 1      9
product 1      12
product 2      7
product 3      6
product 4      10
```

what  I actually  get  is   an  empty  DataFrame.  **NOTE:**  this works  if  I don't  filter  to get unique values  except  it does not  give  me  duplicates with dif. prices

my script:

```
import camelot
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import re

re_filter = re.compile(r'^[A-Z]')
pdf_data = camelot.read_pdf('test.pdf', pages='all', flavor='lattice', encoding='latin-1' )# # GETS Tables
list_of_df = list()# LIST HOLDS  ALL  DATAFRAMES 
prev_df = []# # LIST HOLDS  ARRAY  WITH ENDING  SITE  COL AS  DIGIT

for table in pdf_data:# iterates over  all dataframes 
    df = table.df.rename({0:'product_no',1:'description', 2:'quantity', 3:'net_price', 4:'total'}, axis=1)
    site = df.iloc[-1, 0]
    df =df.reindex(df.index.drop(0)).reset_index(drop=True) 

    if re.match(re_filter, str(site)):          # CHECKS IF  SITE STARTS LIKE  'USCA'  INSTEAD OF  THIS '112233'

        if len(prev_df) > 0:                    # CHECKS  IF  'prev_df' HAS  ANY DATAFRAME IN IT
        
            prev_df.insert(1,df)
            df =pd.concat(prev_df)              # TRYS TO CONCATENATE CURRENT DATAFRAME WITH STORED ON 'prev_df' DATAFRAME 
            df["site"] = site
            df.drop(index=df.index[-1], axis=0, inplace=True)# THIS IS  DROPING LAST ROW  OF  'prev_df -->need to Move '
            list_of_df.append(df)
            prev_df.clear()                     # Removes item in   Prev_df

        else:
            # makes normal  changes to current DataFrame
            df['site'] = site
            df.drop(index=df.index[-1], axis=0, inplace=True)
            list_of_df.append(df)

    else:
        prev_df.insert(0,df)                    # APPENDS  INCOMPLETE  DATAFRAME  TO  'prev_df'

master = pd.concat(list_of_df)


# FILTER UNIQUE  LIST  OF DESCRIPTIONS
un= master.dropna().groupby('description')['net_price'].unique()
print(un)
# master_filtered = master.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)

#   currently gets  data  in this format               need to  display like this 
#   | service1   |   4    |  site1                                 | site1 | site2 | site3 | site4 | site5 |
#                |   2    |  site2                     service 1   |   4   |   2   |       |       |   4   |
#                |   4    |  site5
serv= master.pivot_table(values='quantity', index=un, columns='site', aggfunc=np.sum)
print(serv)

serv.to_csv('test2-output.csv')
```

Comment: Why is the value for product 4 "4" and not "10"?

Comment: Sorry !  Typo, I manually  entered the  data

Comment: Seems like you're trying to use drop_duplicates()

Comment: I have  tried   `un= master.groupby('description')['net_price'].unique()`   same result   just  2 extra  blank  lines  wen printing  "`un`"

Comment: aahh   i  get it !  was not aware  there was a  drop_duplicates()  function. would this  be used in the   group by    , instead  of  unique() ?

Comment: master.drop_duplicates(subset=['description','net_price']).sort_values(by='description')

Comment: Hey this  actually  filter   "`un`"    however  when i try  to  use it   as in index   in the   `pivot_table()`  i still get an empty table

Comment: master.pivot_table(index='description',columns='site',values='net_price')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239140/discussion-between-victorr-and-nev1111).